# Accessing a common Facebook account. Facebook authentication and access tokens

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, access-token, facebook-oauth, facebook-android-sdk

I'd want to allow all users of a mobile app to post to a same Facebook account, account whose credentials I don't want them to know... I'd simply want to make it transparent to users, I mean, I'd like to show users an app dialog where they could write a message and post it to a certain Facebook account, and let users know they are posting to a certain account, but I dont want them to know the credentials of such account and have to login on it.

So, firstly, I need to avoid the Facebook's login dialog being displayed to my users. As far as I know, it is possible to skip the login dialog step if you already have an access token. On the other hand, it seems that an access token identifies a user... then, could a same access token be used by several users? I guess that, at server-side, that would be as receiving requests from an only user, but is there any problem in that?

Has somebody faced a similar scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook release an access token only if the user is logged id. You can't post something if the user isn't logged in.
If you use your own facebook app, user still has to log in and allow connection to your app. Then you can post on user's wall, but you can't avoid login altogether

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Login and permissions need to be granted only once, right? Could it be possible to do some tricky thing, that having an administrator who logs in the app before the rest of users get it, to get the access token and then store it in a database where also update it when deperecated, or something like that?

Comment: Access tokens have a short life, exactly to forbid uses such what you want to do...

Comment: I see... and if administrator requests it again when expired? Is the scenario where users access their own account the only common one? Is not there any example of an app where users post or update content to a unique wall?

Comment: If users are members of a group then they can post to the wall of the group. But each one has to be authenticated individually